# C++ template class instantiation for obj size reduction

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, porting, visual-c++-6

We are migrating our product from VC6 to VS2012. Our product comprises many (>100) projects with > 1M lines of code. We have heavy template usage.
After migrating the projects and building we noticed the product size drastically increased, more than 30 fold, mainly the .obj files' size increased.
An idea was raised that templates are the reason, since some template classes are used in almost every object.

I've found IBM solved this problem using [TEMPINC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v6r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.cbcpx01%2Fstempl.htm)
But I can't figure out how to use similarly on VS 2012.

I would also appreciate any ideas on what else could cause the compilation products to inflate.

Comment: Are you actually concerned about the obj file size or the final executable size?

Comment: Both, obj size is also impotent because of developer hard drive limitations

Comment: Depending how you do it, debug symbols can end up contributing a lot of obj file size. You could try a non-debug build to check. (And you do realise big hard drives are really cheap now, don't you?)

Comment: @AlanStokes Release build is much lighter, but still huge even compared to the debug build on VC6. Developers need the debug information, and since I'm a developer buying new hard drives isn't my domain. Also the large build products impact build time, which won't be solved by larger (and usually slower) hard drives.

Comment: What Debug Information Format are you using? `/Z7` puts everything in the `.obj` file, so the files will be big. `/Zi` and `/ZI` uses a second file, a `.pdb` so the obj file is smaller, and maybe you could use a second HDD for the PDB file?

Comment: VS2012 also supports the new feature of ["extern templates"](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=549) which may help in reducing the repetition of common template instantiations.

Comment: @cdmh We compile with /ZI

Comment: @MikaelPersson I can't grasp how extern templates should be used in case of many files, where should the extern template be? every file?

Comment: @Gilgr Yes, they have to be declared pretty much in the same header as where the templates are declared. IOW, you have header with a class template declaration / definition, and towards the end of it, have a list of common instantiations declared as extern templates. Then, you have to add a simple cpp file that includes that header and contains a list of corresponding explicit instantiations, which needs to be compiled and linked with any code that use those instantiations. I know this isn't a perfect solution, and can mean a major overhaul, but it's one option to consider.